# Scons: combining multiple targets into one

Tags: scons

I have several environments in my project.
When I use target `target1` to build some binaries and shared libraries.

I want to use target `target2` to build a binary and do everything that gets done for `target1`

I would like to achieve following,

1. Build and install `program1` and `library1` for command `scons target1`
2. Build and install `program1`, `program2` and `library1` for command `scons target2`

What is the right way achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your intent: Are `target2` and `target1` Aliases, or actual targets (program/library)? Do you want to be able to call `scons target1` to build program #1, and call `scons target2` to build program #1 + #2? Please list the exact commands that you'd like to call, together with an explanation of the expected output.

Comment: tried to make question clearer. Although build system uses scons there are lots of python modules that changed default scons behaviour. For that reason I wanted to know what is the correct way to combine multiple targets in different environments into one target in pure scons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to combine multiple targets under a symbolic name is the `Alias()` command. Check out the UserGuide at http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html , especially Chapter 25. "Alias Targets". Note that an `Alias` is a target node itself, so you can combine multiple defined Aliases #1-#3 into a global Alias like:

```
alias1 = Alias("alias1", "target1")
alias2 = Alias("alias2", "target2")
alias3 = Alias("alias3", "target3")
Alias("all", [alias1, alias2, alias3])
```

, where you can also replace each "target" string with a reference to an actual file/dir node as it gets returned by a Builder...

Comment: Thanks, it made how `Alias` works clear to me. Is there a way to use an alias which would get defined later stage. I have one alias which gets defined by a custom script after all the sconscripts are scanned.